# Get array from sortable jQuery serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery sortable with 3 list items with the following ID's

```
id_1
id_2
id_3
```

This gets sorted by the user and serialized using the following code

```
var order = $("#rank").sortable('serialize');
saveResponses(order);
```

and printed. Which looks like this...

```
id[]=1&id[]=3&id[]=2
```

So I've got a couple of questions...

1. Why does the underscore get converted to "[]="
2. Is there a strait forward way to get an array of the original ID's? I mean without just doing a string split, and replacing the characters?

Comment: Please have a look at the official [Docu](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize): `It works by default by looking at the id of each item in the format "setname_number", and it spits out a hash like "setname[]=number&setname[]=number".` so far for your `serialize` problem

Comment: To get an `array` of the ids simply use the build-in function [`toArray`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`serialize`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize) converts the data into a *query string*.  The data is formatted (converted to an array) so you can use it in a URL as a query string (GET data).

You probably want [`toArray`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray):

```
var order = $("#rank").sortable('toArray');
```